# C dummy operations

Tags: c

I cant imagine what the compiler does when for instance there is no lvalue for instance like this :
number>>1;
My intuition tells me that the compiler will discard this line from compilation due to optimizations and if the optimization is removed what happens?
Does it use a register to do the manipulation? or does it behave like if it was a function call so the parameters are passed to the stack, and than the memory used  is marked as freed? OR does it transform that to an NOP operation?
Can I see what is happening using the VS++ debugger?
Thank your for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the generated assembly?  I am sure the compiler will simply eliminate the expression.  There is no standard compliant answer here, the compiler can do whatever it wants as long as the semantics of your program remain the same.

Comment: Actually, *if* `number` is `volatile` the compiler **must** tread carefully and cannot just eliminate the expression - reading a `volatile` variable could potentially have side-effects.

Comment: Nik, Can you tell me why the compiler must not discard a read from a volatile when the statement containing the read has no side-effect itself? I don't see anything that supports your assertion in the standard. Is there some clause there you're referencing?

Comment: @MikeB C says that accessing a volatile object has side effects, 5.1.2.3.2 in C11

Comment: §6.7.3.6 of the C99 standard it says: "An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects." Also, §5.1.2.3 "*Accessing a volatile object*, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment."

Comment: The whole point of the `volatile` declaration is that accessing it can have side effect unknowable to the compiler. For example, the memory address may be mapped to some hardware, so that "reading" it is in fact accessing the physical device.

Comment: Thanks, Nik!  I was looking at the C++ standard out of habit (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) and not at the C99 document (ISO/IEC 9899). Surprisingly, the C++ standard doesn't seem to contain the description you found in the C99 document!

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, it discards the operation. It knows the operation has no side effects and therefore doesn't need to emit the code to execute the statement in order to produce a correct program. If you disable optimizations, the compiler may still emit code. If you enable optimizations, the compiler may still emit code, too -- it's not perfect.

You can see the code the compiler emits using the `/FAsc` command line option of the Microsoft compiler. That option creates a listing file which has the object code output of the compiler interspersed with the related source code.

You can also use "view disassembly" in the debugger to see the code generated by the compiler.

Using either "view disassembly" or `/FAsc` on optimized code, I'd expect to see no emitted code from the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I did some experimentations with this on VS++ with and without optimization. They give the same result when no lvalue is given nothing is done. There is no instruction even for the initialization (number=0) !!!
But something interesting happens as told by Nick, when it's volative some other instructions appear at the "Disassemby" starting from the initialization step volatile int number and for the bitshift instruction.
I think I need to understand deeper what does volatile mean.
Thank you all for you help .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `number` is a regular variable of integer type (not `volatile`) then any competent optimizing compiler (Microsoft, Intel, GNU, IBM, etc) will generate exactly NOTHING. Not a `nop`, no registers are used, etc.

If optimization is disabled off (in a "debug build"), then the compiler may well "do what you asked for", because it doesn't realize it doesn't have side-effects from the code. In this case, the value will be loaded into a register, shifted right once. The result of this is not stored anywhere. The compiler will perform "useless code elimination" as one of the optimization steps - I'm not sure which one, but for this sort of relatively simple thing, I expect the compiler to figure out with fairly basic optimization settings. Some cases, where loops are concerned, etc, the compiler may not optimize away the code until some more advanced optimization settings are enabled.

As mentioned in the comments, if the variable is volatile, then the read of the memory reprsented by `number` will have to be made, as the compiler MUST read `volatile` memory.

In Visual studio, if you "view disassembly", it should show you the code that the compiler generated.

Finally, if this was C++, there is also the possibility that the variable is not a regular integer type, the function `operator>>` is being called when this code is seen by the compiler - this function may have side-effects besides returning a result, so may well have to be performed. But this can't be the case in C, since there is no operator overloading.

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I did some experimentations with this on VS++ with and without optimazation. They give the same result when no lvalue is given nothing is done !!!
00FB101C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
 int number=0,result=0;
00FB101E  mov         dword ptr [number],0 
00FB1025  mov         dword ptr [result],0 
    number<<1;

}
00FB102C  xor         eax,eax

Comment: So it's optimizing even when you have no optimization. That's not entirely unexpected.